# React Native Android app Network request failed for any HTTPS URL

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Recently I have been facing "Network request failed" issue with the React Native Android app on physical devices. **Strangely it works fine on the Emulator but fails only on physical devices be it Android 7, 8, etc.** I have upgraded Android Studio to latest, React Native to latest, but still getting this issue.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log("MYJSONRESPONSE", json))
  .catch(e => console.log("ERRORRESP", e))
```

Above is a simple API call, even if I put any other working API URL it will still show the same Network error. Some of the other sample APIs I tried https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user?limit=10 https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```

This happens on a fresh react native project as well even on 0.62 or 0.65

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1"
  }
```

Anybody with any solution for this issue?

Comment: Is your device working on the network?  Can you go to a website in the browser on it?  Can you hit the url manually in the browser?  This sounds more like a network issue on the device.

Comment: Everything is working on the Android devices I have used for testing. The only problem is the React Native app throws "Network request failed" error in debug mode as well as release mode of the Android app on the physical device. While it works perfectly fine on the emulators.

Comment: Is this happening on Android only?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the Description as well. That the Network request failed issue happens with Android physical device only. It works perfectly fine on the Android Emulators and iPhone Simulators as well.

Answer (score 1):

the issue has been resolved and the solution was,

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic (adding this line in android Manifest file)
```

(optionally) setting up network security group for the system/custom domains.

```
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config
```

> **Important note:** When testing on physical devices or even emulators, please make sure you are connected to a working Internet
> connection. I struggled for a few hours just because my Internet was not
> working properly and the "Network request failed" error in that case
> was coming due to "No Internet". Everything was working fine once the Internet was up again.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you add a www, like `https://www.jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`

Comment: I tried that as well, but none of the APIs seem to be working on the physical devices while it works perfectly fine on the emulators. The problem is with the physical devices where other apps and websites are working fine on the device. Even the API works on the browser of that device but not in the Android app.